# sscanf and trailing characters

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to use `sscanf` for a simple test and conversion, but I'm running into a problem with it ignoring trailing garbage in the string.  My example code is:

```c
char *arg = "some user input argument";
int val = 0;
if (sscanf(arg, "simple:%d", &val) == 1) {
    opt = SIMPLE;
} else if (strcmp(arg, "none") == 0) {
    opt = NONE;
} else {
    // ERROR!!!
}
```

This works fine for expected inputs, e.g.:

```
arg = "simple:2"  --> opt = SIMPLE  val = 2
arg = "none"      --> opt = NONE    val = 0
```

But my problem is that *trailing* characters after the "simple" value are silently ignored

```
ACTUAL : arg = "simple:2GARBAGE" --> opt = SIMPLE  val = 2
DESIRED: arg = "simple:2GARBAGE" --> ERROR!!!
```

What's a simple way to get sscanf to report the trailing garbage?  Or, since I've read "scanf is evil", is there a simple (perferably 1-liner) alternative to `sscanf` to solve the above problem?

Comment: Thanks hmjd, that answers my question!  Couldn't find it with my search terms.  Hopefully this question will help lead someone to the same solution.

Comment: `scanf()` is evil.  `sscanf()` is not `scanf()` and used properly works fine.  One of the biggest issues against `scanf()` is that as it combines I/O with parsing and when this goes wrong, it is difficult to re-establish where in the I/O stream to continue.  `sscanf()` only parses, it performs no I/O.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sscanf()` for an extra `char`.  Fail on finding it.

```
char ch;
// If _nothing_ should follow the `int`
if (sscanf(arg, "simple:%d%c", &val, &ch) == 1) Success();
// or if trailing white-space is OK
if (sscanf(arg, "simple:%d %c", &val, &ch) == 1) Success();
```

The other idiomatic solution uses `%n`

```
int n;
// If _nothing_ should follow the `int`
if (sscanf(arg, "simple:%d%n", &val, &n) == 1 && arg[n] == '\0') Success();
// or if trailing white-space is OK
if (sscanf(arg, "simple:%d %n", &val, &n) == 1 && arg[n] == '\0') Success();
```

Comment: Simple, effective.  I like it.  The only downside is that all these solutions seem to require a temporary variable of some sort.  But it doesn't look there's any way around it.

Comment: @ɲeuroburɳ _Could_ use `sscanf(arg, "simple:%d%c", &val, &arg[0])`, as by the time `%c` is encountered, `sscanf()` must be past `&arg[0]`.  But that is a bit of a [kludge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge).

Comment: lol.  Suppose you could do `sscanf(arg, "simple:%d%c", &val, (char*)&val)` too.  :)  All things being equal, I like your answer better than your kluge. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following:

```
char rest[64] = "";
[...]
if ( sscanf(arg, "simple:%d%s", &val, rest) == 1 ) {
```

and test the contents or length of `rest`.

This works because the `%s` following the `%d` will eat any characters following a valid number. You can adjust the size of `rest` as necessary for your needs.

See [here](http://codepad.org/2A9roQnm) for a working example.

Comment: That's similar to the path I've been trying out since posting the question.  I'm thinking it might make sense to use a length qualifier on the '%s' conversion for safety.  E.g. `"simple:%d%1s"`.  Then rest can be a char[2].

Comment: This method does not detect tailing white-space.  Although `'%s'` does eat any characters following a valid number, if it only encounters trailing white-space characters, nothing is saved in `rest()` and `1` is still returned.

Comment: @ɲeuroburɳ Good point on that. Then you don't have to worry if `rest` is large enough.

Comment: A length as proposed by @ɲeuroburɳ is needed to guard against excessive trailing non-white-space characters.  But since only a _single_ occurrence needs detection, code could use `char rest[2]; ... sscanf(arg, "simple:%d%1s", &val, rest) ...`

Comment: @chux Thanks, and good point about trailing white-space.